# Netlogo R Extension: user.properties file missing

Tags: r, netlogo

I am trying to use the R extension in Netlogo 6.2.

I just cannot find the user.properties file anywhere.

I have Windows 7. According to instructions:

- I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2013
- I configured the Windows PATH adding C:\Program Files\R\R-\bin\x64\ after a semicolon
- I reinstalled Java to the latest version
- I installed java packages and loaded the library in the R session that I am running in R Studio, using the following console commands: install.packages("rJava") and library(rJava)
- I added the "extensions [ r ]" line at the top of the code in Netlogo

Now: I am getting Error 01 for lack of configuration of the user-properties file.

("LALC" is my username).
So I am looking for the user.properties file into
C:\Users\LALC\AppData\Roaming\NetLogo\6.2\r
and there is nothing in there!

Where is the user.properties file?

There is also nothing in the extensions folder.

I don't understand if I should create the user.properties file myself, and if yes, what should I write in it?

(FYI I am running Windows 7 on a Mac, using Bootcamp, but I don't think this should be an issue, correct?)

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258816/how-to-use-r-extension-in-netlogo-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

I believe I solved the problem.

As discussed, after all the installation steps, the user.properties file was missing in

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NetLogo\6.2\r

I found it in a completely different folder which is

C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.2.0\app\extensions.bundled\r

I copied it from there and pasted it in

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NetLogo\6.2\r

This is not mentioned at all in the Netlogo instructions document at
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/r.html
and I think it should be clarified.

Anyway, now with the user.properties file in the correct location, after editing it with the correct location paths for r.home and jri.home in the Windows section (asking for those paths in R, as per instructions), and of course uncommenting those lines, I finally open the Netlogo file with the "extensions [ r ]" line at the beginning ... and I get no more error notifications.